# Почему не работает alert() и следующие за ним команды?

Tags: javascript

```js
let valid = true;
let x = prompt("Введите x", "");
if (x == null || x == "") {
  alert("Вы не ввели x");
  valid = false;
}

if (valid == true) {
  let n = prompt("Введите n", "");
  if (n == null || n == "") {
    alert("Вы не ввели n");
    valid = false;
  }
  alert("n = " + n);
  alert(valid);
}

function pow(x, n) {
  let poweredNumber = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    poweredNumber *= x;
  }
  return poweredNumber;
}
alert("Перед if");
if (valid == true) {
  alert("В if");
  alert(pow(x, n)); //Почему-то не срабатывает
}
alert("После if"); //Почему-то не срабатывает
```

Не работают части, которые я отметил комментариями. Но причем не работает только, если объявить переменную valid и прописать первые два if'а. Если valid и первых двух if'ов не будет, то всё ОК. По сути всё должно работать, но что-то не так...

Comment: какие значения x и n ты вводишь?

Comment: @Grundy 5 и 2 .

Comment: Перенес твой код в сниппет, сейчас ошибка должна стать очевидной.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

переменная `n` объявлена с помощью [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), следовательно она видна только внутри блок `if`.

Поэтому при вызове `alert(pow(x, n))` происходит ошибка, так как нет переменной `n`.

Для решения достаточно вынести объявление `n` из `if`, либо заменить `let` на `var`